# Android camera2 Image orientation problem

Tags: android, android-camera2

How could I make my image orientation same as preview image in camera api2 and set `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`, which will force the window rotation to a fixed value?

Generally, I try to get the mobile orientation when using capture action, but with the portrait setting, it doesn't work.

```
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()
cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION)
```

I know how to set a right orientaion, the problem is how to know the orientation used during the capture action?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use my method to solve your Portrait capture [Solution to your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56664653/how-to-convert-yuv-to-bitmap-in-landscape-orientation).

But one of my problem is when force landscape and reverse landscape currently.